# assign ng-model to ng-repeat (for dropdown selection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, dropdown

This is with reference to the jsfiddle attached herewith. 
http://jsfiddle.net/n1cf938h/

As shown in the fiddle, ng-repeat produces a list of dates. I want to know which dropdown selection user has selected. How can i use ng-model in this case ?

HTML-

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select>
          <option ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS code

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.baseAdd = 0;
$scope.dates = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(function(day) {
dateobj = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (day + $scope.baseAdd)));
    while(dateobj.getDay() == 6 || dateobj.getDay() == 0) {
    $scope.baseAdd++
  dateobj = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (day + $scope.baseAdd)));
}
return dateobj;
});
console.log($scope.dates)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) as it implements exactly this for you. Here is your fiddle with an example using ngModel and ngOptions

http://jsfiddle.net/x67udrcg/

Whenever the dropdown changes, `$scope.selectedDate` will hold the new value

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select ng-options="date as date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' for date in dates" ng-model="selectedDate"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for showing me how to use ng-options for my case. it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the selection box using `ng-model` and `value` like this:

```
<select ng-model="date">
    <option value="1-1">1-1</option>
    <option value="1-2">1-2</option>
</select>
```

In your case, this also works:

```
<select ng-model="date">
    <option ng-repeat="date in dates">{{date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</option>
</select>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/na0bs2ox/

Comment: @Ealon- i cannot assign value as mentioned by you. since i am using ng-repeat to display all the dropdowns and not individual option tags

Comment: @Ayesha Wait a min, I am writing a Jsfiddle for you.

Comment: See my answer. Angular has already solved this for you with ng-options

Comment: @CharlieMartin Saw your answer. You are right, it is better to use ng-options which makes everything more Angular-ish. Somehow, I cannot get rid of jQuey thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `ng-model="someVar"` as an attribute on the `<select>` tag.

Then you can use it from within the controller as `$scope.someVar`.

Comment: @koster1889- can i get a result for $scope.someVar with this ? there are no values assigned currently to the option tag. due to ng-repeat, assigning  different values to dropdown doesnt seem to be possible here

Comment: I got something like that working... It might be good to look into ng-options instead of ng-repeat. It's a directive specifically for this situation.